# Swift - Which trait collection to use?

Tags: swift

There are a ton of ways that I found to get the current `userInterfaceStyle`, but I can't tell what is the most appropriate method of getting it.

There are four ways that I found:

1. `UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle`
2. `UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle`
3. `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle`
4. `traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle`

I generally used number 4 whenever I had to make a global function, and just had the trait collection as a parameter. Doing that seems unnecessary, though. There should be a universal variable. Which of these should we be using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UITraitCollection.current` is a special call that is used in order to get the interface style when you're in a graphics drawing situation. So it isn't really related to the other three.

As for those three, there can be different trait collections / user interface styles at different levels of the hierarchy, and there are different ways to refer to the various objects that comprise the hierarchy. So I can think of a dozen more ways to get the trait collection! But when you want to know the trait collection, you should just ask for the one at the level of the hierarchy you are interested in. Usually this will be the one closest to where your code is. For example, if this is view controller code or view code, you will usually ask for `self.traitCollection`.

Comment: Thank you! In the case that I have a global function that is not inside a specific view controller or view, which of the other two should be used? Or would it be better to pass `self.traitCollection` as a parameter into the function?

Comment: Personally I think the phrase "global function" has a bad smell right from the start. :) But yeah, I'd need to see why you have a "global function" and what it does, in order to make a judgment about that.

Comment: This is my function:
`func systemDarkMode(_ style: UIUserInterfaceStyle) {
    save.set(style == .dark, forKey: SaveKeys.isDarkMode)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .darkMode, object: nil)
}`

Comment: Well, I dont get it; there is no mention of a trail collection in that code.

Comment: that's because wherever I happen to use this code, I pass in self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle as a parameter

Comment: And that seems fine.

Comment: Was looking for this, rendering views as `UIImage` works perfectly with `.current`